# Spring integration with cache and http.outboundGateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to implement the cache to avoid multiple calls to Rest API. Below is the implementation code for `API call`.  Instead of calling API every time, I need to put the `API` results in hashmap using payload object as key and result as value. I tried different ways but I was not able to find the solution. Please, can you help me with this.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow read() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("input").split(new PayLoadSplitter()).enrichHeaders(p -> p.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/service/publications/{name}")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).expectedResponseType(String.class).uriVariable("name", p->p.getPayload())).aggregate().get(); 
}
```

Comment: Wish I could see an answer for this! Did you find a way, I've this requirement now.. Googling.